# Are there any studies on a sorting function on real line?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, monotone-functions

Let assume we have an integer array $[3,4,1,0,7]$, we can sort it into $[0,1,3,4,7]$.

There is a sorting function $S: \mathbb{N}^k \to \mathbb{N}^k$ that sort the integer in the array defined as above.

If we see an integer array as a function that maps an index set $\mathcal{I} \to \mathbb{N}$, I want to generalize it to the case that $\mathbb{N}$ is replaced by $[0,1]$ of a real line.

In this continuum case, **are there any studies on the analog to the 
 sorting function $S$ but on real line in the sense that it "sorts" a real-valued function $f(x)$ defined on $[0,1]$?**

i.e. a function $S': F[0,1] \to M[0,1]$, where:

$\mathcal{F}[0,1]$ are all function from $[0,1] \to [0,1]$,

$\mathcal{M}[0,1]$ are all monotonic increasing (non-decreasing) function from $[0,1] \to [0,1]$.

that somehow preserves the values of $f(x)$. I am not sure how to define what it preserves precisely now (I guess should be related to derivative), just a weird idea.

**EDIT followed by David C. Ullrich's answer**

What if we restrict $\mathcal{F}[0,1]$ to be some kind of "nice" function, such as differentiable almost everywhere on $[0,1]$?

Comment: What would be the difference between what you are describing and simply "finding the range of $f$"?

Comment: I am interested in the properties of the functional mapping that map (project) a function $f$ to a monotonic increasing function $g$ described above.

Comment: also, what $g$ looks like. Why I think it is related to derivative, imagine a function $f(x) = 2x $ if $x \in [0,\frac{1}{2})$, $2-2x$ if  $x \in [\frac{1}{2},1]$. $g$ should be simply $g(x) = x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well first we need to define what it means to "sort" a function $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$. Given what seems like the natural definition (below) there are functions that cannot be sorted.

> > **Definition** Suppose that $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$. To *sort* $f$ is to find a bijection $\phi:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that $g=f\circ\phi$ is nondecreasing.

Let $f$ be the characteristic function of the irrationals in $[0,1]$. Or if you want an injective example, to clarify that breaking ties is not the issue, define $$f(t)=\begin{cases}t,&(t\in[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q),
\\2+t,&(t\in[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q).\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ cannot be sorted. Because if you could sort $f$ then $[0,1]=A\cup B$ where $A$ is countably infinite and every element of $A$ is less than evey element of $B$; this is impossible, since every infinite initial segment of $[0,1]$ is uncountable.

**Edit:** Smoothness doesn't help. Simpler example than the above, also smooth: Let $f(t)=\sin(\pi t)$. If $\phi$ is a bijection and $g=f\circ \phi$ then $g^{-1}(1/2)$ contains exactly two points, but if $g$ is monotone then $g^{-1}(a)$ is either a singleton or infinite.

Comment: your definition is good. Dirichlet-like function would always be a good counter-example. What if we restrict the function to be "nicer", let's say differentiable almost everywhere on $[0,1]$

Comment: @wonghang No, smoothness doesn't help. See edit.

Comment: If i follow your counter-example's argument, my own example of $f(x) = 2x$ on $[0,\frac{1}{2})$, $f(x) = 2-2x$ on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ would also be not sortable, which I think (naturally) mapped to $g(x) = x$. I somehow think the definition, $\phi$ does not preserve "some kind of density" as in its discrete counterpart.

Comment: Indeed, a bijection $\phi$ need not be measure-preserving. There _is_ a notion of "non-decreasing rearrangement" in measure theory; the non-decreasing rearrangement of your example is indeed $g(x)=x$.

Comment: sorry. I try to rethink your edited answer and get lost. If $g$ is monotone, then $g^{-1}(a)$ is either a singleton or infinite. I think $g$ is not necessary to be strictly monotone? Let $g(x) = a$, then $g$ is non-decreasing while $g^{-1}(a)$ is whole $[0,1]$?

Comment: what you said about non-decreasing rearrangement is beyond what I know. I need to google first

Comment: If have no idea what you're asking. If $g$ is non-decreasing or non-increasing, $s<t$ and $g(s)=a=g(t)$, then $g=a$ on all of $[s,t]$.

Comment: arr...I got it now. thx